# como puedo obtener la Dirección ip de mis usuarios usando python

Tags: python

anteriormente intente con esto y no resulto me retorna la ip del servidor y no la
ip del usuario que debo de hacer para que me retorne la ip del usuario ya estando en el servidor

```
import socket
nombre = socket.gethostname()
addr = socket.gethostbyname(nombre)
```

Comment: Hola Zara, no se si realmente es el mismo problema que planteas en tu pregunta anterior: [Mi sitio web me da la dirección ip del servidor y no la del usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/280510/15089). Si es así, ¿has probado lo que comenta eyllanesc? De todas formas request.remote_addr no siempre va a funcionar en producción porque se suele estar bajo proxies, por lo que sería bueno que dieras más datos sobre el entorno en el despligas tu app y su configuración (mod_wsgi, apache, nginx, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Hola al parecer utilizas sockets en tu proyecto es este caso intentemos:

```
import socket
nombre = socket.gethostname()
addr = socket.gethostbyname(nombre)
```

Esto no funcionara por ser socket la variable/import socket en tu servidor por ende todos los datos son de tu servidor 'Ip del servidor :('.

Si intentamos con:

```
# Esto es mi configuración del socket
s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM ) 
s.bind( (HOST, PORT) ) 
s.listen(1) 
# Estas son las variables del cliente
conn, addr = s.accept()
clientIP = addr # Aquí se guarda la IP del cliente
s.close()
```

Donde clientIP es uno de los valores de la conexión aceptada por tu servidor de un cliente. Específicamente la IP de tu cliente :3, y claro conn es la conexión ya con esto lo solucionamos

Comment: gracias por ayudarme

Comment: @Zarabezos Si la respuesta funciono agregala como respuesta aceptada. Fue un placer ayudar.